# about unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing, orm

Q:
My question consists of three parts:

1-i wanna to ask how to make a unit testing for a method this method use another method to connect the database(the layers concept or ORM)..

2-is the unit testing can make a test among my methods(the contracts among them) how??and please an example to clarify this point?

3-when i know that my unit testing is just wasteful and not that important one ,, i wanna to make unit testing to avoid errors..

please feel free to explain as possible ,,any resources suggestions ...etc

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important design aspect is to have weak coupling between the different layers of your application. This weak coupling could be achieved by introducing interfaces and abstract classes. This way the different layers of the application are not strongly coupled.

The weaker coupling allows for easier mocking of those dependencies in your unit test so that you never depend on a database call for example.

So let's take as an example the following interface:

```
public interface IProductsRepository
{
    Product Get(int productId);
    void Save(Product product);
}
```

Now you could have a service layer which would depend on this repository:

```
public class ProductsService
{
    private readonly IProductsRepository _repository;
    public ProductsService(IProductsRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void SomeBusinessOperation(int productId)
    {
        var product = _repository.Get(productId);
        // TODO: update some properties of the product
        _repository.Save(product);
    }
}
```

As you can see the service class is now weakly coupled to the repository. You could then very easily unit test it in isolation. Just pick a mocking framework such as [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) and in your unit test generate a mocked repository implementation to be feeded to the service constructor and be able to test the business operation in isolation of any database.

Comment: i have three layers in my web application:(data access layers which contains connection to data base),(the managers which contains the CRUD and which use the data access layers),(the interface layer)

Comment: @user418343, that's nice, now you might take a look at some mocking frameworks such as Rhino Mocks which would allow you to generate mock objects in your unit tests and substitute the dependencies of the class you are testing with this mock object.